# Get first block quote inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text area which can contains more than block quote what I want to do is to get the value of the first block quote which located directly after the open tag of the text area.

HTML CODE

Case 1 :

```
<textarea>
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">

  <blockquote>
    I want to grab this text
  </blockquote>

  <blockquote>
    I don't want this text
  </blockquote>

  </div>
</textarea>
```

Case 2 :

```
<textarea>
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">

  <blockquote>
    I want to grab this text
  </blockquote>

  </div>
</textarea>
```

Case 3 :

```
<textarea>
  <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;">

  <p>
    Good afternoon, gentlemen. I am a HAL 9000 computer. I became operational at the H.A.L
  </p>

  <blockquote>
    In this case I don't want to grab anything
  </blockquote>

  </div>
</textarea>
```

Jquery CODE

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
  var content = $(this).val();
  var blockquote = $(content).find('blockquote:first').text();

  alert(blockquote);
});
```

The Jquery code above works fine in case 1 and 2 but not working in case 3.
[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ex4t7ob2/)

Comment: Your jQuery gets the first blockquote within the textarea in all three example. So what's the problem?

Comment: Whats your Problem? The COde does exactly what its suposed to do

Comment: @j08691 I want to get the block quote which located directly after the open tag of the text area not after a p tag or any other tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `first-child`:

```
var blockquote = $(content).find('blockquote:first-child').text();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ex4t7ob2/1/).

Comment: It worked fine but it gave me empty value in case 3 how I can avoid it.

Comment: `if (!blockquote) { return; }`

Answer (score 0):

You Need to get the First Child of the Text Area and then build an IF-Condition wich tests if the Tagname is `blockquote`.